# Get rid of pop up list on input

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, html-lists

Im following a tutorial on making an autocomplete feature. However, I want to scroll up and down my countries list, but the black list isn't allowing me to. Its a list of my previous entries in that input. It wont allow me to scroll through the list of countries with my arrow keys.

Is there a way to make that disappear?

[image]

I have no clue where to even start.

Answer (score 0):

try using incognito mode or delete the data stored in your browser

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).